# VB 2013: how to update database using datagridview values

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, auto-update

I have a DGV in my form that can be edited. I want to write back the updated values to the database so that they are available for next read.

I searched for answers around net and found couple of ways of doing it by opening a connection and updating it. However, i was wondering if there is any direct way of updating the database by using a single command.

I am a novice at VB and learning it only for a library project, hence find it difficult to understand and implement statements that deal with SQLs in the code. pls help... thanks

Answer (score 0):

The proper approach to this is to use a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` that you then bind to the grid, then use the same data adapter to save the changes from that table back to the database.  E.g.

```
Private adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyTable", "connection string here")
Private builder As New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
Private table As New DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Query the database and populate the DataTable.
    adapter.Fill(table)

    'Bind the data to the UI.
    BindingSource1.DataSource = table
    DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    BindingSource1.EndEdit()

    'Save the changes back to the database.
    adapter.Update(table)
End Sub
```

The `BindingSource` would be added to the form in the designer.